# Overwrite jquery expander css

Tags: jquery, css

I need to overwrite the css of the plugin http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/ from display:inline-block to just inline. Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
afterExpand: function() {
   $(this).find($('span.details')).css('display','inline');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in your CSS with:

```
span.details{
    display:inline !important;
}
```

if I missed the class name, inspect your expanded element, get the right class and target it.